# How to stream data from locally installed SQL Server to Kafka topic on confluent cloud, without installing Kafka in the local machine

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, confluent-cloud

SQL Server database is in local system
Kafka is configured in confluent cloud
Operating system of the local machine is Windows 10
Is there any way without installing Apache Kafka in the local machine to stream data out from SQL Server database to Kafka topic on confluent cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install Apache Kafka locally in order to stream data from your database.

Since you are using Confluent Cloud it is easiest to use one of the two available managed connectors for getting data from SQL Server. Since you're using a local machine you're going to have to make sure you can expose it on a fixed IP and port (the connector is "pull" from Confluent Cloud and not a "push" from your local machine, if that makes sense).

- [Debezium connector](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-microsoft-sql-server-source-cdc-debezium.html#cc-microsoft-sql-server-source-cdc-debezium)
- [JDBC connector](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-microsoft-sql-server-source.html#cc-microsoft-sql-server-source)

Which connector you use depends on factors covered [briefly here](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/data-pipelines/cdc-data-from-rdbms-into-kafka/) and in [more detail here](https://rmoff.dev/no-more-silos).

Comment: Thanks Robin, Do i need to install Debezium connector in my local machine?

Comment: My local machine is getting data from some sensors (accelerometer and magnetometer), data are stored in the local machine database i.e. MSSQL. Now, how to connect this local database with kafka topics in confluent cloud to sent data from MSSQL to topics in cloud?

Comment: @Pran As answered, you'd need to expose your database such that a remote connector _running in Confluent Cloud_ (nothing local) can query it

Comment: Can you let me know how can I expose MSSQL to remote/cloud kafka connector,.it will be great help

Comment: Please start a new question for that, it's separate to this one (it's more to do with Windows networking and your local network than Kafka)

Comment: (Also, why not get your sensors to write to Kafka directly? )